# Visual studio code notification asking if I want to exclude Java project settings files or not

Tags: visual-studio-code

I suddenly got this notification when open a flutter project in vs code:
Do you want to exclude the Visual Studio Code Java project settings files (.classpath, .project. .settings, .factorypath) from the file explorer? (options: Exclude Globally, Exclude in Workspace, Never)

I chose Never for the time being, but I was wondering what it even implies?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a prompt that comes from the Java extension from VS Code:

https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/blob/06793b174437fee55985c62917f08da926f37058/src/settings.ts#L73

I guess it's asking whether you want those java-related project files to show up in the VS Code explorer side bar, or be hidden (if you choose to exclude, it will write exclusions into your VS Code settings so they are hidden).